# Autofocus not working on AF-S 35mm 1.8 DX with Nikon D3100

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting, nikon-d3100

I haven't been using my camera very much over the past few months. The few times I've pulled it out, I noticed that the autofocus doesn't work when I put on my 35mm prime. I tested my 55-200mm and 18-55mm and their autofocus works. I have made sure that both the camera and lens are set to AF. I cleaned off the lens contacts with a cloth and isopropyl alcohol.

Is my only option at this point getting it refurbished? I'm not sure I have a warranty still; the lens was bought in November of 2012 but I didn't register it until October 2014.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: It is most probable that the objective is malfunctioning if other objectives work fine. Yes you need to service it.

Comment: It will likely be pretty affordable. I had a 28070 2. D that stopped auto focusing last year. I did all of the the things you did too. It was very affordable and turned out to be a loose internal contact.

Answer (score 2):

It might sound silly but have you checked the button on the side of the lens? I thought mine wasn't working until I noticed I had set it to manual.

Answer (score 1):

Do you hear any sound while you try to focus (the noise of focus motor)?
If not, you'll need to send it to an authorized service center.

If you hear the sound and the lens is still not focusing, the issue is with the focus screw inside the lens. It still needs service, but repair costs would be less since motor is working.

Additionally, the issue could be some (minor) loose connection at the terminals.
Remove lens and clean the terminals at the base of the lens carefully. Reattach the lens, and try taking photos.

If the focus still does not work, service would be the only option.